# Why are some Spark batches taking longer to read data from Kafka?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka

Low Kafka latency in random spark batch with kafka cluster

I have a spark structure streaming app which reads data from a kafka topic and do some ops and again writing output into kafka topic. I do not understand why few of spark batches are taking very less time (1 or 2 sec) to read data from kafka and few batches are taking longer time(40 or 42 sec). I am receiving continous stream of data(fixed eps of 2500).I am using kafka culster having 3 broker and 8 kafka log directory each broker. My topic partition is 4 as I am using 4 executor in spark-submit command.

Can anybody suggest why this is happening or any other suggesting/changes that can fix this issue.

[image]

Why the computation time on executor hbase1 is very high s compared to other 3 executors(ref image 2nd[image]).

Comment: To read same amount of data/same eps from kafka topic in kafka cluster spark structure streaming job is taking 40sec and sometime just 2 sec. why this is happening ?

Comment: Are those executors running on nodes with less IO usage? Is the hardware located closer to the Kafka brokers? Are all the executors running the same hardware?

Comment: I have three broker kafka cluster on three separate nodes and I am running my spark job on 2 node separate hadoop cluster. These 2 node have 4 core each.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the solution for this problem. Actually there is bug in the kafka-client connector jar coming along with spark-structure streaming in version-2.3.1.So, I excluded that jar and added separate dependency of kafka-client jar in my pom file and it worked as expected. Now I can see in my every spark job there is a constant read time from kafka topic.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
  <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11</artifactId>
  <version>${spark.version}</version>
  <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>net.jpountz.lz4</groupId>
            <artifactId>lz4</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
  <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
  <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
  </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
<artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
<version>0.10.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I also found that this bug is being fixed in the later version(spark - 2.4 )